# Acrobat XI Pro: Allow User Input to Override Auto-Calculate Formula

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I have this form, an official form (a character sheet for use at an Organized Play Event for a role-playing game, if it matters to anyone), that someone kindly turned into a [fillable PDF form](http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=1089). I asked a question earlier about [checkboxes and auto-calcualtions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471285/acrobat-xi-pro-checking-status-of-a-checkbox-to-affect-calculation), and got that to work...but now I need to account for another variable (situational doubling of the Proficiency Bonus) in some of my calculations. Unfortunately, this variable is not represented anywhere on this form, and I can't just add fields to the form (it being an official form, at least when printed). **Without adding more fields to the (printed) form, how can I account for this additional variable?**

I thought about just allowing the user to override the auto-calculation by typing in the field, but I can't figure out how to make that happen. Is this a good solution? Is this relatively simple to code?

If your answer involves adding code to my form, please include a code snippet I can modify, and a description of where I should insert it into my existing code, or if there is somewhere else I need to be adding it instead.

---

Code Sample:

```
//check bonus = stat bonus + applicable proficiency bonus

var profUse = this.getField("SklAcrProf").value;
var stat = Number(this.getField("DEX1").value);
var profVal = Number(this.getField("Proficiency Bonus").value);
var check = Number('-2');

if (profUse != "Off"){
    check = stat + profVal;
}
else{
    check = stat;
}

event.value = check;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form only needs to remain the same, when printed, the simplest solution may be to go ahead and add the fields that you need.  You can set them up, so that they are "visible but doesn't print".  This option can be selected in the Form Field drop-down list, in the Text Field Properties, General Tab, under Common Properties.

This way, you can still incorporate the data in your formulas, but it has no affect on the printed document.